# How can I invalidate a sound?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, touch

I have two methods pertaining to my question, touchesBegan and touchesEnded. I want to code it so when you touch it (touchesBegan) that the sound starts (or plays) and then when you let go of the screen (touchesEnded), that the sound invalidates.

I already have AudioToolbox imported and declared it as systemsoundID and everything, but I'm not sure how to invalidate it for touchesEnded and then have it start again when you touch the screen again.

Right now it only plays once when I put it in touchesBegan, in the beginning. And when I put it in touchesEnded, it plays every time I let go (kind of the opposite of what i want, but it doesn't invalidate it like I want as well) I just want it to only play the audio while im touching and to end the sound as soon as I let go.

The code I was using for the .m in touchesEnded/Began was

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(PlaySound1);
```

Comment: use AVAudioPlayer. It has stop, start and pause functions. Google a tutorial on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(PlaySound1);`

to cancel the current sound that is playing but it isn't really encouraged. I would recommend using AVPlayer which has the ability to play the sound in a loop as well as start and stop the sound. You can check it out [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Chapters/Reference.html)